# concat two df by two equal columns pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

i got two df with two similar columns but different names , and i want to concat them by the similar columns

that is my df

```
data={"col1":["A","B","D","f"],
"col2":[4,2,4,6],
"col3":[7,6,9,11],
"col4":[14,11,22,8],
"multi":[1.4,2.5,1.6,2.2]}
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

data2={"col5":["A","B","D","f"],
"col6":[345,55,44,16],
"col7":[4,7,4,6],
"col8":[1,5,3,9],
"multi_2":[2,2,4,9]}
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
```

i want to connect them by columns ["col1","col5"]

and it need to look like this but its can be with "col5" too

```
data3={"col1":["A","B","D","f"],
"col2":[4,2,4,6],
"col3":[7,6,9,11],
"col4":[14,11,22,8],
"multi":[1.4,2.5,1.6,2.2],
"col6":[345,55,44,16],
"col7":[4,7,4,6],
"col8":[1,5,3,9],
"multi_2":[2,2,4,9]}
df3=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data3)
df3
```

Comment: ``df1.merge(df2, left_on=['col1'], right_on=['col5'])``

Comment: thank you i try this but i wrote   left_on='col1'
and not  left_on=['col1']
thanks :)

Comment: Yes.. it can be _label or list, or array-like_

Comment: @matan that should still work when you give as a string.

Comment: and if df1 had one more row how can i merge them without losing the row that is not in df2?

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='col1', right_on='col5').drop('col5', axis=1)
```

Comment: and if df1 had one more row how can i merge them without losing the row that is not in df2?

Comment: @matan add `how='left'` or `how='outer'`